# Re-installation from the internet fails with error code -2005F, what does it mean?

Tags: macos, mac, high-sierra

I tried to re-install macOS on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) via the internet (Command+Option+R). After 5 minutes and some progress the following was shown, what does it mean?

[image]

apple.com/support does not know this error code.

Comment: The icon gives it away as a 'failed to connect' error. If you're on wifi, try wiring up instead

Comment: I prefer to first download High Sierra from the Apps Store to the target or other computer. You can then [transfer the download to a flash drive and install from this flash drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you need to reset your device's NVRAM. Check out Apple's documentation that explains how to do that: [How to reset NVRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

This [thread on the Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16146274#message16146274) suggests an NVRAM (or PRAM) reset will resolve this issue. If that doesn't work, it wouldn't hurt to try an [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) as well.

Answer (score 2):

I received the *exactly same* error `-2005F` on T2 `MacBook Pro 16,2` and figured out it's because all partitions have been wiped out on the disk when I tried to install Linux. I just installed a Linux and get partitions configured.